# C basic datatype problem - const char * to LPCTSTR

Tags: c, winapi

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "windows.h"
bool SCS_GetAgentInfo(char name[32],char version[32], char description[256], const char * dwAppVersion)
{
    strcpy(name,gName);
    strcpy(version,gVersion);
    strcpy(description,gDescription);
    notify(dwAppVersion);
    return true;
}

void notify(const char * msg)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT(msg), NULL, NULL);
}
```

I have managed to work with the first three fields fine, but I am running into issues with the const char *. I have tried passing and casting in alot of different ways, but can't get it to work. I googled around, but couldn't find much on Lmsg. I am new to alot of this. I have read around and I think it may have to do with encoding. What really confuses me is LPCTSTR is defined as a const char *, but straight typecasting doesn't give me anything from the field.

I get an error that Lmsg is undeclared which I am guessing means that the Macro expansion of TEXT is causing this. How can I get this working?

Doing `MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)msg, NULL, NULL);` instead gives me a bunch of boxes indicating it probably is referencing the wrong characters, but copying the dwAppsVersion parameter into the description shows the correct information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're building you application to use UNICODE Win32 API's, but you're passing around non-UNICODE strings.  You have two options:

1. convert the `msg` string to Unicode using something like `MultiByteToWideChar()`.  This is probably the 'right' way to do it, if a bit more complex because you need to deal with codepages and managing the buffers used for the conversion.
2. you can force the ANSI version of the API to be used:

   ```
   MessageBoxA(NULL, msg, NULL, NULL);
   ```

That's a simple workaround, if not elegant.

Other options include only building the application to use Win32 ANSI APIs instead the Unicode APIs or changing the strings you pass around as `LPTSTR` and using the `TEXT()` or `_T()` macros for your literals.  However, if you're reading non-Unicode data from files or elseswhere, then you still have to deal with the conversion at some point...

Answer (score 1):

An `LPCTSTR` is an alias for `const TCHAR *`, and `TCHAR` is a type used in Windows programming to ease the transition between the ANSI ([Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), very similar to the internationally standardized [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)) and [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) [text encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

If your project is set up to build your app using ANSI, `TCHAR` is really `char`, and you would be able to pass `msg` to `MessageBox` without a cast.

If your app is set up to build using Unicode (which is what it sounds like), `TCHAR` is really `wchar_t`, and you would have to convert the string from ANSI to Unicode using a function like [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(VS.85).aspx).

Simply casting just forces the compiler interpret the type differently without changing the data; in this case, that's not enough because the actual data must be converted from one format to another.

Comment: Not all "ANSI" strings in Windows are CP-1252.  That's just the default for US English.  It will vary from machine to machine.  Using the `*A` functions should be avoided for this reason.  Build Unicode applications.  If you need to convert to/from a legacy string use `CP_UTF8` with `MultiByteToWideChar`/`WideCharToMultiByte` because UTF-8 can represent anything that Unicode can.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on in your question since you appear to have left some relevant context out.  For example LPCTSTR isn't mentioned anywhere, so I can only guess at what you're talking about, or what "the first three fields" are.

One thing to note is that LPCTSTR is not always `const char*`, it is in an ANSI build, but it is `const wchar_t*` in a Unicode build.  This most likely the issue you're running into.

Also, the TEXT() macro is only for defining string constants.  You can't use it to perform a conversion on a variable, this is why you're getting 'Lmsg undeclared'.

If you aren't intentionally using a Unicode build, you may want to change your project settings to an ANSI build as a work-around.  Otherwise, you may want to read a tutorial on working with Unicode, which you really should be familiar with if you are writing software for Windows these days.